# Flutter ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

> type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of
>   type 'String'

My code:

```
class HomeState extends State<Home> {   List data;

  Future<List> getData() async {
    Network network = Network();
    var response = await network.getData();
    print('response');
    print(response);
    this.setState(() {
      data = response;
    });

    print('data');
    print(data);

//    return "Success!";   }

  @override   void initState(){
    this.getData();   }

  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Listviews"), backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
          return new Card(
            child: new Text(data[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );   } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the network.getData() returns a json. Text widget need a string. If you want simply add each list item to text just call data[index].toString(). Otherwise you need find your value that you need in your json. Imagin you have json with name key so you should use data[index]['name'] syntax.